# Textures in OpenTK appear black when using a shader

Tags: c#, opengl, graphics, 3d, opentk

I started working on a simple game engine and I'm trying to implement some 3D objects.

I have the basics, a simple test shader, but for some reason, the texture always appears as black. I rewrote everything once already, the problem is still there. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I'm very much a beginner when it comes to graphics and OpenGL.

The running project is Game. In GameEngine there is the Mesh code, Shader and Texture2D.

Here is my GitHub repository: [ChronosEngine](https://github.com/chronium/ChronosEngine)

Edit:

Code is now fixed.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't actually read your Code, but usually the issue you describe is caused by a missing light source. Try to apply some light and it might work.

Comment: Add a light source for what? If you didn't read my code then don't comment. My shader doesn't have a light source. It's a simple passthrough shader for a diffuse texture. If I make it a color like red instead of the texture it works fine. So, in conclusion, it has nothing to do with a missing light source.